# Find the sum of two arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, algorithm

I am trying to find the sum of two lists/arrays in Python.

For example:

You are given with two random integer lists as `lst1` and `lst2` with size `n` and `m`  respectively. Both the lists contain numbers from `0 to 9`(i.e. single digit integer is present at every index).

The idea here is to represent each list as an integer in itself of digits N and M.

You need to find the sum of both the input list treating them as two integers and put the result in another list i.e. output list will also contain only single digit at every index.

Following is the code which I have tried:

```
def list_sum(lst1, n, lst2, m) :
    i, j, sum, carry = 0, 0, 0, 0
    new_lst = []
    if n == 0 and m == 0:
        new_lst.append(0)
    elif n > 0 and m>0:
        while n > 0 and m > 0:
            sum = lst1[n - 1] + lst2[m - 1] + carry
            if sum >= 10:
                carry = 1
            else:
                carry = 0
            new_lst.append(sum % 10)
            n -= 1
            m -= 1
        while n > 0:
            if (lst1[n-1] + carry) >= 10:
                new_lst.append((lst1[n-1] + carry) % 10)
                carry = 1
            else:
                new_lst.append(lst1[n-1])
                carry = 0
            n -= 1
        while m > 0:
            if (lst2[m-1] + carry) >= 10:
                new_lst.append((lst2[m-1] + carry) % 10)
                carry = 1
            else:
                new_lst.append(lst1[m-1])
                carry = 0
            m -= 1
        if carry == 1:
            new_lst.append(1)
        new_lst.reverse()
    elif n == 0 and m > 0:
        new_lst.append(0)
        new_lst = new_lst + lst2
    elif n > 0 and m == 0:
        new_lst.append(0)
        new_lst = new_lst + lst1
    print(new_lst)
```

however I feel I am missing something here and which is not giving me proper answer for the combination. Sometimes it errors list out of index error. I don't know why.

The example input:

```
n = 3
lst1 = [6, 9, 8] 
m = 3
lst2 = [5, 9, 2]
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 9, 0]
```

Here, each element is summed and then if the `sum >=10` then we get a `carry = 1` and which will be added with the next sum.

i.e

```
1. 8+2= 10 >=10 hence carry=1 in first sum
2. 9+9+1( carry) = 19 >=10 hence carry=1
3. 6+5+1( carry) = 12>=10 hence carry=1
4. upend the carry to next position as 1
Hence resultant list would be [1, 2, 9, 0]
```

What can I try next?

Comment: What's the issue? Your code works for the given input.

Comment: sometimes it errors list out of index error.. I don't know why.. Can there be other solution which is more concise and works with less time to execute?

Comment: On what inputs does it throw this error?

Comment: I see one instance of one list "indexed by the other index". (An archetypical copy&paste error. The "carry only" part is duplicated without necessity, and overly complicated anyway.) Once the error is fixed, consider [Code Review@SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: To figure out what's wrong with your code, you will need to debug it. [This article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) has some great tips to get you started.

Comment: Now that you have a plethora of suggestions, it would be nice if you could compare them and post the results for documentation purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, all other answers are awesome for adding 2 numbers (list of digits).
But in case you want to `create a program which can deal with any number of 'numbers'`,

> ##### Here's what you can do...

```
def addNums(lst1, lst2, *args):
    numsIters = [iter(num[::-1]) for num in [lst1, lst2] + list(args)]  # make the iterators for each list
    carry, final = 0, []                                                # Initially carry is 0, 'final' will store the result
    
    while True:
        nums = [next(num, None) for num in numsIters]                   # for every num in numIters, get the next element if exists, else None
        if all(nxt is None for nxt in nums): break                      # If all numIters returned None, it means all numbers have exhausted, hence break from the loop
        nums = [(0 if num is None else num) for num in nums]            # Convert all 'None' to '0'
        digit = sum(nums) + carry                                       # Sum up all digits and carry
        final.append(digit % 10)                                        # Insert the 'ones' digit of result into final list
        carry = digit // 10                                             # get the 'tens' digit and update it to carry

    if carry: final.append(carry)                                       # If carry is non-zero, insert it
    return final[::-1]                                                  # return the fully generated final list

print(addNums([6, 9, 8], [5, 9, 2]))                                    # [1, 2, 9, 0]
print(addNums([7, 6, 9, 8, 8], [5, 9, 2], [3, 5, 1, 7, 4]))             # [1, 1, 2, 7, 5, 4]
```

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: I think the comments are not really helpful to understand the code. They're basically just repeating what's already written on the same line, just slightly more verbose. `[next(num, None) for num in numsIters] # for every num in numIters, get the next element if exists, else None` The comment explains that "for" is a for-loop and that "next" gets the next element? `sum(nums) + carry # Sum up all digits and carry` Yes, I can read that.

Comment: You have `final.insert(0, digit % 10)`. This makes your code a lot less efficient than it could be. Inserting at position 0 of a list requires rewriting the whole list. An alternative would be to guess the size of the final list in advance; or to append the digits at the end rather than at the beginning, then reverse the list just before the `return`.

Comment: to the complexity part I agree and have made changes, but talking about that commenting part, different people prefer differently framed comments. It may not be needed to an experienced programmer, but those people who are new to it, will badly need some explanation to these lines, hence the commenting each line makes sure every programmer, whether fresher or experienced, all will get benefitted.

Comment: I agree that your code would greatly benefit from explanations. But a few comments to summarize what the function does as a whole would be much more helpful than one comment per line repeating what that line does out of context. It is completely clear that `digit = sum(nums) + carry` is computing the sum of nums then adding the carry. Writing a comment that repeat that is not helpful at all. What would be helpful would be a comment about the overall function, which would make it easier to understand why you're computing the sum of nums and adding the carry at this point.

Comment: `def addNums(lst1, lst2, *args):` can be replaced by `def addNums(*args):` and `numsIters = [iter(num[::-1]) for num in [lst1, lst2] + list(args)]` by `numsIters = [iter(num[::-1]) for num in args]` to make simpler.

Comment: You didn't get the purpose of putting 2 explicit arguments. The main motto behind it was to make sure the user provides at least 2 numbers in the function call, so that calling to the function makes some sense, otherwise there's no point of calling the function for just 1 number. You can also check other similar methods in programming languages too, they all follow the same analogy!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want it like this:
[6, 9, 8], [5, 9, 2] -> 698 + 592 = 1290 -> [1, 2, 9, 0]

In that case my first idea would be to turn the numbers into strings, combine them to one string
and turn it into an int, then add both values together and turn into a list of integers again...
you can try this:

```
def get_sum_as_list(list1, list2):
    first_int = int(''.join(map(str,list1)))
    second_int = int(''.join(map(str,list2)))
    result = [int(num) for num in str(first_int+second_int)]
    return result
```

Comment: This solution I tried, but the problem is, if any of the list is of size zero, then I need to append the 0 at the beginning of the resultant list.

Comment: if one of the list is empty then wouldnt you just have to return the other list? or do you want something else then. basically you could check for empty lists at the start of the function like 'if not list1: return list2' and  'if not list2: return list1'

Comment: @PujariRajagonda Instead of `first_int = int(''.join(map(str,list1)))`, you can do `first_int = reduce(lambda x,y: 10*x+y, list1, 0)`. This avoids the conversion to `str` and handles the case of an empty list. Where `reduce` is `from functools import reduce`.

Comment: @Stef Interesting. That remains competitive longer than I expected.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible solution:

(i) `join` each list to create a pair of string representation of integers

(ii) convert them to integers,

(iii) add them,

(iv) convert the sum to string

(v) separate each digit as `int`s

```
def list_sum(lst1, lst2):
    out = []
    for i, lst in enumerate([lst1, lst2]):
        if len(lst) > 0:
            out.append(int(''.join(str(x) for x in lst)))
        else:
            if i == 0:
                return lst2
            else:
                return lst1
    return [int(x) for x in str(out[0]+out[1])]

list_sum([6,9,8],[5,9,2])
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 9, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Two other answers show solutions repeatedly converting between lists of int and strings and ints. I think this is a bit cheating and completely hides the algorithm.

Here I present a solution that manipulates the lists of ints directly to build a third list of ints.

```py
from itertools import chain, repeat # pad list with 0 so they are equal size
from operator import add            # add(x,y) = x+y

def padded(l1, l2):
    "padded([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) --> [0, 0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]"
    padded1 = chain( repeat(0, max(0, len(l2)-len(l1))), l1 )
    padded2 = chain( repeat(0, max(0, len(l1)-len(l2))), l2 )
    return padded1, padded2

def add_without_carry_same_size(l1, l2):
    "add_without_carry([6, 9, 8], [5, 9, 2]) --> [11, 18, 10]"
    return map(add, l1, l2)

def flatten_carry(l):
    "flatten_carry([11, 18, 10]) --> [1, 2, 9, 0]"
    c = 0
    for i in range(len(l)-1, -1, -1):
        c, l[i] = divmod(c + l[i], 10)
    if c > 0:
        l[:] = [c] + l

def list_add(l1, l2):
    '''
    list_add([6, 9, 8], [5, 9, 2]) --> [1, 2, 9, 0]
    list_add([9, 9, 9, 9, 9], [1]) --> [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    '''
    p1, p2 = padded(l1, l2)
    l3 = list(add_without_carry_same_size(p1, p2))
    flatten_carry(l3)
    return l3
```

Relevant documentation:

- [builtin function `map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map);
- [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#chain);
- [`itertools.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#repeat);
- [`operator.add`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#add);
- [builtin function `divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod).

Answer (score 1):

Tried the following logic

```
def list_sum(lst1, n, lst2, m, output):
i, j, k, carry = n - 1, m - 1, max(n, m), 0
while i >= 0 and j >= 0:
    output[k] = (lst1[i] + lst2[j] + carry) % 10
    carry = (lst1[i] + lst2[j] + carry) // 10
    i = i - 1
    j = j - 1
    k = k - 1
while i >= 0:
    output[k] = (lst1[i] + carry) % 10
    carry = (lst1[i] + carry) // 10
    i = i - 1
    k = k - 1
while j >= 0:
    output[k] = (lst2[j] + carry) % 10
    carry = (lst2[j] + carry) // 10
    j = j - 1
    k = k - 1
output[0] = carry
print(output)
```

where the output parameter in the above code it taken from below

```
outputSize = (1 + max(n, m))
output = outputSize * [0]
```

and called the function

```
list_sum(lst1, n, lst2, m, output)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention how long your lists will be. So considering they aren't going to be that long (anyway, python can handle bignums), why not making a simple sum operation? In the end that's what the code should emulate.

```
import numpy as np
lst1 = [6, 9, 8] 
lst2 = [5, 9, 2]
lst1_len = len(lst1)
lst2_len = len(lst2)
if lst1_len >= lst2_len:
    lst2 = [0] * (lst1_len - lst2_len) + lst2
else:
    lst1 = [0] * (lst2_len - lst1_len) + lst1

common_len = len(lst1)

lst1_val = sum(np.array(lst1) * np.array([10**(-x) for x in range(-common_len + 1, 1)]))
lst2_val = sum(np.array(lst2) * np.array([10**(-x) for x in range(-common_len + 1, 1)]))
total = lst1_val + lst2_val
total_as_list = [int(x) for x in str(total)]
```

where

```
print(total_as_list)
[1, 2, 9, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Code:

```py
def addNums(*args):
    nums=[]
    for i in args:                                
        if i:
            i = list(map(str,i))               # Converts each element int to string['6', '9', '8'] , ['5', '9', '2']
            add=int(''.join(i))                # Joins string and convert to int  698 ,592
            nums.append(add)                   # Appends them to list [698, 592]

    Sum = str(sum(nums))                       # Sums the values and convert to string '1290'
    result=list(map(int,Sum))                  # Converts to list with each converted to int[1,2,9,0]
    
    return result
print(addNums([6, 9, 8], [5, 9, 2]))  
print(addNums([7, 6], [5, 9], [3, 5],[7, 4]))
print(addNums([]))
```

### Output:

```
[1, 2, 9, 0]
[2, 4, 4]
[0]
```